# Windows 7 [USB Create Copy via Cmd]

Tags: windows-7, usb, cmd.exe

I am trying to create Windows 7 USB copy, that works via cmd. It works for me but when I insert it into my work computer it does not start.

Was wondering if there is any way to change the path so that i don't need to manually change the user name. Here is what I wrote.

```
Copy C:\User\mrx\Documents D:\SilentDrive
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows provides many [pre-populated environment variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104(v=ws.10).aspx) you can use on the command line (or in batch files, etc.).

The one you are probably interested in is the `%userprofile%` variable which contains the current user's profile path (e.g.: `c:\users\UserName`).

So:

`Copy %userprofile%\Documents D:\SilentDrive`

Comment: Thank you so much. I typed what you wrote and i worked fine. Thanks again.